# change the position of f3d objects randomly in action script

Tags: actionscript-3, random

I have a f3d object and have different boxes to place the parts of the f3d objects.When i click on the button change the position of the boxes randomly. How it possible?This is the code for random array.

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point

        var startArray:Array = generateNumberArray(10);
        var randomArray:Array = randomArray(startArray);
        trace("startArray = " + startArray);
        trace("randomArray = " + randomArray);


    }
    /**
     * generate Array of numbers by length
     * @param   length
     * @return Array of numbers
     */
    public  function generateNumberArray(length:int):Array 
    {
        var numberArray:Array = [];
        for (var i:int = 0; i < length; i++) 
        {
            numberArray[i] = i+1;
            //trace("ersexrfegtdrgtdrygtfr"+numberArray[i]);
        }

        return numberArray;
    }

    /**
     * generate randomly mixed array by input array
     * @param   inputArray - simple not mixed array
     * @return Array - mixed array
     */
    public function randomArray(inputArray:Array):Array 
    {
        var randomArray:Array = [];
        var tempArray:Array = [];
        for (var i:int = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) 
        {
            tempArray.push(inputArray[i]);
        }
        while (tempArray.length)
        {
            var randomNumber:int = Math.round(Math.random() * (tempArray.length - 1));// get random number of left array
            randomArray.push( tempArray[randomNumber] );
            tempArray.splice(randomNumber, 1);
            trace("randommmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm"+randomArray);


                 // remove randomed element from temporary aarray
        }
        tempArray = null;
        delete [tempArray];
        return randomArray;

    }
    public function loadCompleteEvent(e:Event):void 
    {
      if (stage) init();
        else 
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);


         // my boxes (want to change the position randomly of these boxes)
        Box2.setPosition(57.49752426147461, -2.987499237060547, 10); 
        Box3.setPosition(57.49752426147461, -26.987499237060547, 10); 
        Box4.setPosition(-48.50247573852539, -2.987499237060547, 10);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the relevance of the random array function, but to set a random position for each box you could create a helper function which returns a random number between `min` and `max`:

```
private function randomNumber(min:Number, max:Number):Number {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

And then set the position of each box using:

```
box2.setPosition(randomNumber(0, 100), randomNumber(0, 100), 10);
```

Adjust the min and max values as you need.